How to Add a Hint Text styling position and layout in Drop down Button in flutter
[OutPut]-this is what i wanted to make(https://i.sstatic.net/0koPZkpC.png)-this is my dropdowni put the images for referencemy code snippet for customdropdown is like this
 Container(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 480),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
    border: Border.all(
      color: selectedValue != null ? Colors.red : const Color.fromRGBO(120, 120, 120, 1),
      width: 0.8,
    ),
    color: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
  ),
  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton2<String>(
      hint: Text(
        hintText,
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 13,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 72, 72, 1),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      items: itemList.map((item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: item['id'],
          child: Text(
            item['name']?.toString() ?? item['id'] ?? 'Unnamed',
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 72, 72, 1),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: onChanged,
      value: selectedValue,
      // Use the id as the value
      isExpanded: true,
      dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
        scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        maxHeight: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 0,
              blurRadius: 4,
              offset: const Offset(0, 2),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
          thickness: WidgetStateProperty.all(0),
        ),
        offset: const Offset(0, -4),
      ),
      iconStyleData: IconStyleData(
        iconEnabledColor: selectedValue != null ? Colors.green : Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

i tried to use diffrent properties of dropdown and also tried asking ai
no result

https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2#7-using-dropdownbuttonformfield2-with-form
